# how to access modified value outside of the ajax-query in ReactJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have posted below a piece of my ReactJS code. In this code, I am receiving a JSON array from server and I am assigning that JSON array to a variable named `this.records`. But the problem is that, I am getting an empty array when I call `this.records` outside of the ajax-query. Please tell how can I get the modified value of `this.records` outside of the ajax-query?

**Code:**

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.records = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/data",
    }).then((function(data) {
        this.records = JSON.parse(data)

        /*this.records prints modified value*/
        {console.log(this.records);}

    }).bind(this));


    /*PROBLEM: this.records does not prints modified value here*/
    {console.log(this.records);}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here's the deal, you are trying to `console.log` the value of the returned ajax in a `sync` way, while ajax works in an `async` way.
Meaning that by the time you reach `console.log(self.records);` (outside the ajax call), the ajax didn't return yet and the data won't show.

You could deal with this in a few ways:

- Refactor your code, use the returned value **from** the ajax response itself
- Make your ajax `async = false` (not recommended)
- Put a `setTimeout` on the `console.log(self.records);` and hope the ajax will finish its call by then. (also not recommended and a bit dumb)

The `this` now refers to the Ajax return function, use this hack:

```
this.records = [];
var self = this;

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/data",
}).then((function(data) {
    self.records = JSON.parse(data)

    /*this.records prints modified value*/
    {console.log(self.records);}

}).bind(this));
```

You could also use a lambda function:

```
this.records = [];

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/data",
}).then(( (data) => {
    this.records = JSON.parse(data)

    /*this.records prints modified value*/
    {console.log(this.records);}

}).bind(this));
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work? could you maybe `console.log(self)` and tell me what it shows? Also, `console.log` the data that returns.